# I had my passport renewed before the expiration date and now I have two valid passports

Tags: visas, passports, passport-renewals, visa-expiration

My Italian Nulla Osta visa is attached to my previous Bangladeshi passport but I renewed my passport and then I submitted it to the embassy and took both my valid passports but the passport with which Italian Nulla Osta visa is attached was not submitted by the embassy. They again took the new one! Will my previous visa from the older passport still be valid?

Comment: Hi Sadia. Your question is hard to understand. When you say "will I get a visa" what visa are you applying for? Why does it make a difference whether your Italian visa is attached? Or are you asking if your Italian visa is still valid? And by "Nula Oster" do you mean "nulla osta" visa? Please edit the question.

Comment: i edited the question again thank you

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about the specifics in Italy but in most countries it works like this

1. When your new passport gets issued, the old one gets invalidated, often by punching a hole through it. But you do get it back.
2. Any valid Visas and stamps in the old passport remain valid. You just need to show both passports to immigration control. There is typically no need to transfer an existing Visa to the new passport.

CAVEAT: each country and sometimes each consulate & embassy  make their own rules. You need to check and verify with the specific authorities for your case.

Comment: And beware that while the immigration people understand this I have had multiple occasions where others did not--including the woman at the airline check-in counter.  Expect to have to explain it sometimes.